# Why is continue making the iteration stop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I don't know why the iteration is stopping once I place a `continue`. If I replace `continue` with `console.log()` it's working fine. What I am trying to do is to return `true` if all elements are the same, and `false` otherwise.

```
function isUniform(de) {
   for(var i=0;i<de.length;i++) {
       if (de.indexOf(de[i])===0) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true;
}

arr =[1,1,1];
isUniform(arr);
```

Comment: You've got a `)` in the wrong place: `if (de.indexOf(de[i]) === 0)`

Comment: You have to read more about [continue statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue). In your situation, you don't have to use `continue` or `indexOf`.

Comment: @robotcookies, actually their code checks that each element can be found at the first index, i.e. is the same as the first element. It correctly returns `false` for your example `[1, 4, 7, 8]`.

Comment: i guess the logic works i tried with python it worked,it means if all the values are same it gives same index everytime that returns true

Comment: My bad... you are correct junvar. I will delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're predicate has a typo:

`de.indexOf(de[i]) === 0`

Also, this may be simpler to implement as:

```js
let isUniform = arr => arr.every(a => a === arr[0])

console.log(isUniform([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
console.log(isUniform([1, 3, 1, 1, 1]));
```

In english, this is checking if every element of `arr` is equal to `arr[0]`.

Comment: that was best but can you write it with continue???just asking out of curiosity why cant i run this way when i wrote the same logic with python worked!!

Comment: arr=[1,12,1,1]
def isuniform(ar):
    for i in ar:
        if ar.index(i)==0:
            print("hi")
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True

Comment: Your example with `continue` is correct barring the typo mentioned in my answer and in the comment below your question.

Comment: Your fixed code works fine. Could you detail what error or unexpected results you are seeing